# glGetMaterialfv and glMaterialfv on Raspberry Pi

Tags: opengl-es, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have found through trial and error that on Raspberry Pi, glGetMaterialfv() will only accept face GL_FRONT or GL_BACK, while glMaterialfv() will only accept GL_FRONT_AND_BACK (other face options cause error GL_INVALID_ENUM).

Is this behavior normal, or is it permitted but strange, or is it a bug?

(I'm using GLES shipped with Raspbian Wheezy 3.18.11+, which I know isn't the latest OS, but I have an early Raspberry Pi that will be slow with the latest Raspbian.)

Comment: In general `glMaterialfv` should accept `GL_FRONT`, `GL_BACK` and `GL_FRONT_AND_BACK `, where `GL_FRONT_AND_BACK` sets the parameters for `GL_FRONT` and `GL_BACK` at once. So for `glGetMaterialfv`, the parameter `GL_FRONT_AND_BACK ` won't make any sense.

Comment: Now that you've pointed this out, it does make sense that the Get function would reject GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, thank you for pointing that out! I'd still like to know why it refuses GL_FRONT on the glMaterialfv though.